# Templating Classes and Aliases Causes Compile Errors

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I have been developing an application using wxWidgets (detail, but not specific to the problem). I have a class called MyPanel, and in it, I have a timer that I start and stop as needed. I use the timer for a number of different purposes, although only one of the purposes can be active at a time. To do this, I have two methods:
StartTimer and StopTimer, both of which must be passed the timer handler to bind/unbind when the timer is started or stopped. To simplify the code, I use an alias for the handler type. Here is the declaration:

```
using TimerHandler = void (MyPanel::*) (wxTimerEvent&);

class MyBasePanel : public wxGLCanvas
{
   ...
    std::unique_ptr<ShaderProgram> m_program;
    ...
}

class MyPanel : public MyBasePanel
{
    ...
    void StartTimer(TimerHandler handler);
    ...
}
```

So with this, everything compiles and runs. Now the problem. I want to have multiple classes derived from MyBasePanel, each using a different ShaderProgram class and different handlers. So, I changed my class declarations as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class MyBasePanel : public wxGLCanvas
{
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_program;
    ...
}

template <typename T>
class MyPanel : public MyBasePanel<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Now when I attempt to compile, Visual Studio gives this error on the alias:

> 'MyPanel': use of class template requires template argument list

OK, so I changed the alias to:

```
template <typename T>
using TimerHandler = void (MyPanel<T>::*) (wxTimerEvent&)
```

and the StartTimer (and StopTimer) method declarations to:

```
void StartTimer(TimerHandler<T> handler);
```

Now Visual Studio spits out:

> 'MyPanel::StartTimer': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
>
> note: see declaration of 'MyPanel::StartTimer'
>
> note: definition
>
> 'void MyPanel:StartTimer(void (__cdecl MyPanel::* )(wxTimerEvent &))'
>
> existing declarations
>
> 'void MyPanel:StartTimer(void (__cdecl MyPanel::* )(wxTimerEvent &))'

Note that the definition and declaration are the same. Some investigating indicates that the C++ standard does not really allow combining aliasing and templating in this way.

I have come up with one potential solution to this problem that I think will work. Instead of passing in the handler to the StartTimer and StopTimer methods, pass in a flag, then test the flag and bind/unbind the matching handler. I haven't tried this, but I think it will work. My concern is that this seems kludgy and very C-like; there should be a more C++-like solution.

How do I change what is above to "work"?

Comment: Can you show the definition of your StartTimer function ? Its definition if outside class should look like 'template <typename T> MyPanel<T>::StartTimer(TimerHandler<T> handler)'.

Comment: @Arunmu

> template <typename T>
> void MyPanel<T>::StartTimer(const int timerInterval, TimerHandler<T> handler)
> {
>     m_timerNumber = GetTimer();
>     // MSW has limited number of timers, so we must check that we got one.
>     if (m_timerNumber != NOTIMERS) {
>         m_startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
>         m_timer = std::make_unique<wxTimer>(this, m_timerNumber);
>         m_timer->Start(timerInterval);
>         Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, handler, this);
>         wxBeginBusyCursor();
>     }
> }</pre>

Comment: Based on you comment, I think you can employ something similar to what I have shown in the answer. Do you see any issues with that ?

Comment: Haven't had time today to try it out. Will answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going ahead posting this solution as it works on both clang and g++. It seems that you are using visual-studio, so, I cannot tell whether this solution would work for you or not.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
using Timer = void (U::*)(); // This is your timer.

// A small template meta-program to make sure that your
// Timer<T> type actually points to some callable object.
// It is needed to make sure that the type T in 'Timer<T>'
// is indeed Mypanel or similar class and that has a function named
// cb (can be changed as well)
namespace meta_detail {
template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_cb(const T& obj, int) -> decltype(std::declval<T&>().cb(), bool())
{
  return true;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_cb(const T& obj, long) -> decltype(std::declval<T&>().cb(), bool())
{
  return false;
}
}

template <typename T>
class Test {
public:
  template <typename U>
  void take_it(Timer<U> t) {
    // This is where the meta-program helps you. Compile time
    // Checking.
    static_assert(meta_detail::has_cb(U(), 0), "Nopes!");
    (this->*t)();
  }

  void cb() {
    std::cout << "Callback" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test<int> tt;
  Timer<Test<int>> timer = &Test<int>::cb;
  tt.take_it(timer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to figure out what I was doing wrong.

And yes, your program builds and runs using Visual Studio